# rate my (C++) code: a recursive strstr sans any standard library string functions :)

Tags: c++, recursion

So, the idea was a write a recursive function that compares two strings to see if string 'prefix' is contained in string 'other', without using any standard string functions, and using pointer arithmetic. below is what i came up with. i think it works, but was curious - how elegant is this, scale 1-10, any obvious funky moves you would have done instead?

thanks.

```
bool is_prefixR(char* prefix, char* other) {
  static int prePos = 0,othPos = 0; 
  //  static int othPos = 0;
  bool test;
  test = ( *(prefix+prePos) == *(other+othPos)); //checks to see if same

  if (!*(prefix+prePos)) { return 1; } //end of recursion
  if (!*(other+othPos)) { return 0; }

  if (!test) {
    othPos++; //move othPos pointer by 1
    prePos = 0; //reset the prefix position
    return(is_prefixR(prefix, other)); //lets try again
  } else { //chars are the same
    othPos++; //move othPos pointer by 1
    prePos++;
    return(is_prefixR(prefix, other)); //lets try again
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And which rating are you going to accept? ;-)

Comment: It's called "tail-recursion".  A good code generator detect this and transforms it into a loop.  Code generators do a very good job at turning crappy source code into good machine code.  It is up to you to find out if yours does.  A bit unlikely btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is 1AM and far to late for understanding code, however such a simple function should be really easy to comprehend and your code isn't. Static variables when writing functions are not a good idea because they make it incredibly hard to debug as the function ceases to become stateless. Try passing the values you need to the next function, and if you find you can't, try writing it a different way. You also used prefix in the wrong way. I think you meant substring.

I present two functions below that do what you want and are fairly foolproof with everything except strings that are not null terminated. It is not quite as fast as it could be, as `is_substr` will continue to try and compare even when `other` is shorter than `sub`. You seemed to indicate elegance was the name of the game though, so I avoided all added complexity.
Note: `is_substr` depends on `is_prefix`.

```
bool is_prefix(const char* prefix, const char* other) {
    if ( *prefix == 0 ){
        return true;
    }else if ( *other == 0 || *prefix != *other ){
        return false;
    }
    return is_prefix(++prefix, ++other);
}

bool is_substr(const char* const sub, const char* other) {
    if ( *other == 0 ){
        return false;
    }else if ( is_prefix(sub, other) ){
        return true;
    }
    return is_substr(sub, ++other);
}
```

Just to give you an idea of the functions output

```
is_substr("aab", "aaab"); //1
is_substr("ab", "ba"); //0
is_substr("aab", "a"); //0
is_substr("a", "bab"); //1

is_prefix("a", "a"); //1
is_prefix("a", "ab"); //1
is_prefix("ab", "a"); //0
is_prefix("aab", "aaab"); //0
```

Comment: incidentally, this wont work for the aab & aaab case outlined in interjay's comment i suppose.. this would be some much easier iteratively

Comment: `is_substr("aab", "aaab") = 1`, as aab is in aaab

Comment: I don't think it handles the case of other length less than suffix length. In that case, after matching few characters..the first condition of is_prefix becomes true and returns true.

Comment: As far as I can make out, it works in all cases I have tried, including when the first argument exceeds the length of the second argument. `*prefix` is only 0 when it has successfully matched every other character. Otherwise it would have returned false.

Answer (score 11):

1. This won't work correctly on all strings. For example: prefix="aab", other="aaab"

   - Don't use static variables. The function will fail the second time it's called because of them.
   - Don't use recursion: for long strings you can get a stack overflow. Use a loop instead.
   - The name "prefix" is used for a string appearing at the beginning of another - this is not the case here.

Comment: ah! have to do it recursively, and using just two parameters - hence the statics.. i guess ill have to re-think this.

prefix is indeed misleading, shld fix that - since its checking for mor than just being a prefix..

Comment: In that case, you can increment the pointers instead of keeping the prePos and othPos variables.

Comment: 3. stack overflow is just fine on this site!

Comment: I don't understand how stack overflow can occur in this case, as they are actually pointers to strings. Please clarify.

I would say its good to have static variables they don't actually take up space in the symbol table and the stack memory. They will be data segment of the stack and that increases performance.

Comment: Each recursive call takes a certain amount of stack space. At some recursion depth, you run out of stack.

As for static variables, they will have wrong values the second time the function is called. Even if you fix that somehow, the function will work incorrectly if called from multiple threads at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say its elegance is 0 compared to `size_t pos = string1.find(string2);`

The standard library is there for a reason. Use it. Even if you wanted to create `strstr`, which is a C function and not a C++ function, you really don't need to avoid using `strcmp`. And even then, implementing `strcmp` yourself in a separate function is going to make this clearer.
On top of that, your `static` variables make this function only work once. You're doing it wrong.

From your wording, it sounds like this may be a homework question? In which case you should add the homework tag, and say exactly what the requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

The use of

```
static int prePos = 0,othPos = 0;
```

makes this function not thread safe. Are you sure that's what you want?

`othPos` will grow forever, so this function only works once, after the first
time othPos won't begin with a valuie of 0.

I think if you are going to be using pointers, then you should be incrementing the pointers and passing modified pointers around rather than passing the base pointer down and having all of the work happen in the static ints.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove all the unecessary parens? But even then I would give it zero in the elegance stakes. The first thing an elegant function must do is to perform one task, and your description of the function - "compares two strings to see if string 'prefix' is contained in string 'other'" simply doesn't make any sense. a prefix must begin a string, not be included in it.

Answer (score 0):

//psuedocode

```
if prefix == 0
   return true
else if other == 0
   return false
else return (*prefix == *other) && is_prefix(1+prefix, 1+other);
```

Comment: this is totally wrong. If prefix = "abc" and other = "xabc" this returns false.

Comment: yep, there is no way of incrementing other and not prefix.

Comment: "prefix" means beginning in my dictionary. "abc" is not a prefix of "xabc", it is a suffix.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to use recursion (bad idea, but let's suspend judgement for the moment), you can do it much more cleanly than that:

```
bool is_prefixR(char* prefix, char* other) {
  if (!*prefix) return true;
  if (*prefix != *other) return false;
  return is_PrefixR(prefix+1, other+1);
}
```